# Mamp pro 3.2.1 memcached install osx mavericks

Tags: memcached, pecl, mamp-pro

i just updated to osx mavericks mamp pro 3.2.1 and tried to get memcached running but i dont find any precompiled memcached.so that works. i get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x0A 0x0A 0x0A 0x3C 0x21 0x44 0x4F 0x43 in Unknown on line 0
```

i have latest memcached installed via brew. i suppose building from source will be last resort but i dont find any tutorial for mamp pro and pecl that works so far - any ideas?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: see my answer below - worked for me

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it:

install memcache or any other extension for mampp pro and different php versions:

update/upgrade pecl before:

```
$ sudo pecl upgrade
```

1)
check which php version is enabled in shell

```
$ which php
```

/usr/bin/php is not correct it must be the php version of mamp install e.g.
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/
to change php version edit bash profile

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and change the path to php executable

2)
make sure php source for php version is existent in include folder
go to the target php version mamp dir e.g. /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/ then

```
$ mkdir include
$ cd include
$ mkdir php
$ cd php
```

if the include/php folder exists do nothing since php source is installed
get the php source from: http://php.net/get/php-5.4.42.tar.gz/from/a/mirror 
(make sure you download correspondent version)
copy the content of unzipped into /include/php then

```
$ chown -R setcookie:admin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/include
$ chmod -R 0775 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/include
```

go to folder /include/php and execute:

```
$ ./configure --without-iconv
$ sudo pecl install memcache
```

install the extension or any other extension
go to the extension dir:

```
$ cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

and make sure extension exists and has right owner and permissions

```
$ chown setcookie:admin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so
$ sudo chown setcookie:admin
```

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so

3)
go to mamp app and edit php.ini template to add the line
extension=memcache.so